# git work on both branches, merge into each other?

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-branch, git-merge

This might be a question too trivial for stack... but I'll give it a shot.

I have two branches, prod and master. I have done work on both separately (bugfixes on prod and development on master), now will I have to merge them into each other to bring both of them up to speed, or is there another preferred way of doing it or best practice?

Master does not yet contain the bugfixes contained in prod, and prod is obviously not up to speed with the latest enhancements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this before...  I've merged `prod` into `master` and then deal with any merge conflicts that might come up based on the enhancements you've coded.  That way, when you go to merge `master` into `prod` later, you'll be all caught up and should have no merge conflicts.

Comment: You might also go a step further and branch off master, merge prod into that feature branch so that you can resolve any conflicts there, then merge the feature branch into master, and eventually merge master into prod.